# how to pass react-intl as argument in react component method while jest testing, throws 'TypeError: intl.formatMessage is not a function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am doing unit testing for my react component(using jest). I have few methods that are called from the component.
For Example:

```
    export function getText(text, intl) => ((text !== 'NA') ? (intl.formatMessage({ id: value })) : '');

    const ReactComponent = (props) => {
       const text = getText(text, intl);

       return (....);
    }

    export default injectIntl(ReactComponent);
```

in test file i have:

```
    import { getText } from 'path';
    import { intl } from 'react-intl';

    it('should render text', () => {
      expect(getText('string', { intl })).toBe('string');
    });
```

When i try to run test, it throws error intl.formatMessage is not a function.

Comment: About `it throws error reactcomponent.getText is not a function`. How are you importing this method in your test?

Comment: Import { getText } from 'path';

Comment: That's the reason then. You are not exporting `getText`. I've just updated my answer :)

Comment: As mentioned in question, I tried implementing export function getText()...{..}, still get 'not a function error'

Comment: Could you please update your question then? You are not exporting it. `export default injectIntl...` **will not** export `getText` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you already solved the problem yourself. For everyone else struggling with this problem, I would like explain how I solved it using Jest, Enzyme and TypeScript.

### The problem: mocking react-intl

```
'TypeError: intl.formatMessage is not a function'
```

I experienced the exact same issue. In my case this was caused by mocking the react-intl module. I did not mock formatMessage() which was why I received the undefined function error.

### Official helper function does not work with mocked react-intl module

There is an [official helper function](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Testing-with-React-Intl#helper-function-1) for testing with Enzyme. However for me it did not work with the mocked react-intl module because IntlProvider and other dependencies of react-intl were also beeing overriden by the mocked module.

### Solution

First I created a dummy InjectIntl object, which I gave as prop to the respective component. The object contained the mocked defintion of formatMessage() which returned the default message passed by the calling intl.formatMessage call.

```
export const getDummyIntlObject = (messages?: any) => {
    const intl: InjectedIntl = {
        ...,
        formatMessage: ({ defaultMessage }) => defaultMessage,
        ...,
    }
    return intl
}
```

---

```
export const TestComponent: React.FunctionComponent<InjectedIntlProps> = ({ intl }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img alt={intl.formatMessage(messages.testImageAltText)} />
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

With the returned defaultMessage I could test wether or not the correct string was where I expected it to be.

```
const props = {
    intl: getDummyIntlObject(),
}

describe('TestComponent', () => {
    ...
    test('translations correct', () => {
        const w = shallow(<TestComponent {...props} />)
        const imageAltText = 'This is a test image'
        ...
        expect(w.find('img').prop('alt')).toContain(imageAltText)
        ...
    })
})
```

Please checkout my [gist](https://gist.github.com/arm0nic/7c1ba82a98d02778300ce3c906449afa) for a full code example.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getText` method requires 2 arguments (`text` and `intl`).

```
const getText = (text, intl) => ((text !== 'NA') ? (intl.formatMessage({ id: value })) : '')
```

is the same as:

```
const getText = (text, intl) => {
  if (text !== 'NA') {
    return intl.formatMessage({ id: value })
  }

  return ''
}
```

You are currently calling your test method with `getText('string')`. Consequently, `text` (first argument) **is different than `NA`** and `getText` is going to return `intl.formatMessage(...`). 
Since you didn't provide `intl`, you method will eventually break. That's why you got `it throws another error 'formatMessage is not a function'` message.

While testing, make sure you are **exporting** `getText` so you can use it.

Instead of

`const getText = (...)`

Use:

`export const getText = (...)`

so then you can use it as:

`import { getText } from 'path/to/gettext'`

Comment: I do pass intl to getText in test, it throws intl.formatMessage is not a function.

Comment: @user8870784 How do you pass it? Your example doesn't seem to send it.